# how to make VueJs chart multiply color

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs2, bar-chart

how to set multiply color with data > 5000 is red otherwise it green

now I use

`...
plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            color: "#36A2EB",
            formatter: (value, ctx) => {
              if (ctx.datasetIndex == 0) return "฿" + value;
              else return "";
            },
            anchor: "end",
            align: "end"
          }
        }
...`

it can change 1 label color

Comment: Which library are you using? vue-chartjs?

Comment: I use vue-chartjs